# dynamic drop down form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, cascadingdropdown

I'd really like to have a drop down form using JavaScript. I need it to create a question essentially. How it works: The person, from the home page, will click "Create a Question" and it will go to the Create a Question page. On that page, the first question it asks the person is "What type of question would you like to ask?" and then, via a few radio buttons, they can select which type they want, either "Multiple Choice", "Select the Best" or "Short answer". From that point, more of the form appears…in other words, depending on which type of question they want to ask, a different set of criteria is asked for them to fill out before submitting to the server the question they'd like to ask. Does this make sense? Here is my form so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Quick Bump</title>
            <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="center">

            <h1 class="welcomeHeader">Create a Question:</h1>
            <form action="http://www.example.com/profile.php">

            <p class="pStyle">Please select what type of Question you'd like to ask:
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="radio" name="genre" value="Multiple Choice" checked="checked" /> Multiple Choice
                <input type="radio" name="genre" value="Select the Best" /> Select the Best
                <input type="radio" name="genre" value="Short Answer" /> Short Answer
            </p>
            <br />

            <p class="pStyle">What is your Question?
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Q:<input type="text" class="resizedTextBox" name="Question" /></label><br />
            </p>
            <br />

            <p class="pStyle">What are the answers available?
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>A:<input type="text" class="resizedTextBox" name="Answer 1" /></label><br />
                <label>B:<input type="text" class="resizedTextBox" name="Answer 2" /></label><br />
                <label>C:<input type="text" class="resizedTextBox" name="Answer 3" /></label><br />
                <label>D:<input type="text" class="resizedTextBox" name="Answer 4" /></label><br />
            </p>
            <br />

            <p class="pStyle">Would you like to submit this question now?</p>
            <input type="submit" class="submitLink" name="submit form" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="footer">
        <a href="firstWebPage.html" class="links">Home</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to incrementally show each successive paragraph as the previous form element is changed.

Here's an example to hopefully get you started: 
http://jsfiddle.net/kevincollins/uarZb/

```
$(function () {
    $('.pStyle:first').show();
    $('input[name="genre"]').change(function(){
        $('.pStyle:eq(1)').show();
    });
    $('input[name="Question"]').change(function(){
         $('.pStyle:eq(2)').show();
    });
    $('input[name^="Answer"]').change(function(){
         $('.pStyle:eq(3)').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, that seems to make sense. I will work with this and update you if I have any questions, but seriously, thank you!

Comment: oh actually I have one. So should I make a separate file for this code, or should I place it in the create a question file?

Comment: Either way would work, but it's usually better practice to put scripts in separate files.

Comment: So then, if I'd like to make it so that the next thing shows up only if the person hits an "ok" button, instead of clicking outside the box or hitting tab, is there a way of doing this? what about clearing certain pStyle things if someone selects a different radio button?

Comment: So I figured out how I can hide a section once I select a different radio button, but if I input the same string of text, in the "enter a question" area, if I hit tab the enter an answer part doesn't show up :S

Comment: Sounds like maybe because the change event didn't fire. You could try .blur() instead. http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: hmmm...I was thinking maybe it's possible to have something like:

        $('input[name="qButton"]').change(function(){

But this doesn't actually work...it stops from "tabbing" to the next section, however when clicking the button, that doesn't advance it either.